# Pylint fail under does not fail my Github action job

Tags: python, command-line, github-actions, pylint

I am trying to implement a python linter using pylint. But i am getting the score of each python file and also displaying the suggestion to improve the score but I am also looking to terminate the GitHub action job if my pylint score is below 6.0 but currently its not failing my job.

This is the workflow which I have used :

```
name: Python Linting
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'test'

jobs:
  linting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
         python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install pylint
            pip install umsgpack
            pip install cryptography
            pip install pylint-fail-under
      - name: Analysing the code with pylint
        run: find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint-fail-under --fail-under=7.0 --enable=W {} \;
```

My goal is the show that pylint has failed for a file and then terminate Git-hub action job. But i am not able to implement it using this can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your command in "Analysing the code with pylint" step to return code != 0.

You are using https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html which ignores completely the exit code or `exec` part and will return always 0, unless there is an error in iterating over files.

You have to combine `find` with `xargs` instead - then your exit code will be coming from your pylint command instead of `find`.

The find + xargs will go through all resources and nonzero status if any of executed command returned nonzero status.

If you would like to stop on the first file not passing the lining I would recommend using `set -e` and writing the script differently:

```
set -e
for file in **/*.py; do pylint "$file"; done
```

Comment: Hi one more thing this approach is having an issue when i tested it fails when the score is above 7 as well. What could be the reason? It is giving exit code 0 could that be the reason ?

Comment: I could find that pylint will return 0 if everything is fine in the code. So is there a way to add that condition in the for loop ?

Answer (score 4):

`pylint-fail-under` can be removed as pylint has the feature since 2.5.0 which was released a long time ago. You should also be able to use `pylint . --recursive=y` if your pylint version is above `2.13.0` (it does the same thing than `find` in your script)

> Add --recursive option to allow recursive discovery of all modules and packages in subtree. Running pylint with --recursive=y option will check all discovered .py files and packages found inside subtree of directory provided as parameter to pylint.

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.13/full.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-13-0

The final command could be: `pylint --fail-under=7.0 --recursive=y --enable=W`

Comment: I tried to implement this in github action but this does not fail the job nor does it tell python score has been exceeded for a particular file

Comment: Maybe your score is above 7.0 ? The score taken into account would be the mean for all the files not for each files. If you want >7.0 for each file the other answer is the solution AFAIK.

Comment: The other answer does not work it fails even if score is above 9 for a file

Comment: It's hard to reproduce your issue as I don't have your code. I think you should try running pylint locally without github actions, to see if the command work out of the github actions.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally able to fail the build when pylint score is below 7.0

This is the workflow which i have used

name: Python Linting
on:
push:
branches:
- 'test'

```
jobs:
  linting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
         python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install pylint
            pip install umsgpack
            pip install cryptography
            pip install pylint-fail-under
        #lists pyling suggestions to improve the score & pylint score of the file
      - name: code review 
        run: find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {} \;
        #fails the build if one file has pylint score below 7.0
      - name: Analyse code
        run: |
              for file in */*.py; do pylint "$file" --fail-under=7.0; done
```

Refer : [Fail pylint using Github actions workflow if file score is less than 6.0](https://medium.com/@sidharthvijayakumar7/automating-pylint-in-github-workflow-80c84b2ff243)